# Get last 4 record and not get 4 record data laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel

I'm having trouble to write query in laravel to get last 4 record and not get 4 record.

my query is

```
$news = News::where('status','1')->orderby('created_at','DESC')->latest('updated_at')->take(4)->get();

$other_news   = News::where('status','1')->orderby('created_at','DESC')->whereNotIn('id', [$news ->id])->get();
```

i want to get 4 last record data and except 4 last record data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is [$news->id]. $news is a collection and does not have an id property. If you only need the result from $other_news, i would suggest this:

```
$news = News::where('status','1')->orderby('created_at','DESC')->latest('updated_at')->take(4)->pluck('id'); 

$other_news   = News::where('status','1')->orderby('created_at','DESC')->whereNotIn('id', $news)->get();
```

If you need the result from $news and $other_news, I would suggest this:

```
$news = News::where('status','1')->orderby('created_at','DESC')->latest('updated_at')->take(4)->get();

$other_news   = News::where('status','1')->orderby('created_at','DESC')->whereNotIn('id', $news->pluck('id'))->get();
```

'pluck' can be used as part of a query OR on a collection so it's your choice here. 'pluck' basically grabs all the IDs (or whatever column you specify) and creates an array with the values.

Answer (score 0):

first , you have to get 4 news

```
$news = News::where('status','1')->orderby('created_at','DESC')->latest('updated_at')->take(4)->get();
```

then you have to use `pluck('column_name')` function to get only ids

```
$news_ids=$news->pluck('id')->toArray();
```

then pass this array of ids in `whereNotIn('id',array of ids here)`

```
$other_news   = News::where('status','1')->orderby('created_at','DESC')->whereNotIn('id',$news_ids])->get();
```